# linking comments with image

Tags: ms-access, coldfusion, ms-access-2003, coldfusion-10

[image]Currently I have code that does 3 things.

1. It links an image to a clickable word using an Iframe
2. It has the ability to add comments
3. It displays the comments.

What I am trying to do if it's possible is to have the comments that are displayed tied to the image being displayed. Then when anyone submits a comment it is added to the specific list of the comments tied to the image. Is this possible?

In simpler terms is there a way to link an access table with one specific entry in another table.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<cfquery datasource="AccessTest" name="qTest">
    SELECT Account, Image
    FROM ElectricList
</cfquery>

<cfquery datasource="AccessTest" name="qTest2">
    SELECT Account, Image
    FROM GasList
</cfquery>

<cfquery datasource="AccessTest" name="qTest3">
    SELECT Accounts, Remarks, Users
    FROM Comments
</cfquery>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Demo</h3>

        <iframe name="viewframe" style="display:block;height:Float;width:965px;float:left">
        </iframe>

        <cflayout name="myAccordionLayout" type="accordion" width="600px">
            <cflayoutarea title="Electric Accounts" align="left">
                <cfoutput query="qTest">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href=#qTest.Image#" target="viewframe">#qTest.Account#</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </cfoutput>
            </cflayoutarea>
            <cflayoutarea title="Gas Accounts">
                <cfoutput query="qTest2">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href=#qTest2.Image#" target="viewframe">#qTest2.Account#</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </cfoutput>
            </cflayoutarea>
    </cflayout>

    <table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <cfoutput query="qTest3">
        <tr>
            <td>
                #qTest3.Accounts#
                #qTest3.Remarks#
                #qTest3.Users#
            </td>
        </tr>
    </cfoutput>

    <cfform name="insertComments" id="insertComments">
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                <label for="Accounts">Accounts</label>
                <br/>
                <cfinput type="text" name="Accounts" message="Please enter a Comment Title." validateat="onSubmit" required="yes" id="Accounts" size="60">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Remarks">Remarks<br/></label>
                <cftextarea name="Remarks" cols="55" rows="4" label="Tour Description" required="yes" validateat="OnSubmit" message="Please enter your comment here" enabled="no">
                </cftextarea>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Users">Submitters Name</label>
                <br/>
                <cfinput type="text" name="Users" message="Please enter your name here." validateat="onSubmit" required="yes" id="Name" size="10" maxlength="60">
            </p>
            <p>
                <cfinput type="submit" name="insertComments" value="Insert Comments" id="submit">
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </cfform>

    <cfif IsDefined("form.InsertComments")>
        <cfquery datasource="AccessTest">
            INSERT INTO Comments (Accounts, Remarks, Users)
            VALUES ('#form.Accounts#','#form.Remarks#','#form.Users#')
        </cfquery>
    </cfif>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming your current table has images in it along with an ImageID key, you would create a second table for comments linking to Foreign key imageID from your images table in the relationships.   Then you create a sub-form in your main form to display/edit the comments.

That way each comment is linked to only one image, but each image can have multiple comments.

EDIT: Follow this guide for creating a sub-form.

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/subforms/link.php

Comment: How would I create a sub-form

Comment: added link to subform guide

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're saying an image has more or more comments.  If so, this isn't a ColdFusion problem.  You'll want to add a table to your database that reflects that association.